# How to display 4 values in every row in html using ngfor and ngif?

Tags: html, css, html-table, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I want to display key value pair via for loop in table, tr tag. 3-4 pairs I want to display in one row.

Added my code here- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hrqira?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I want to display 4 values each in the row. Updated my question with this link.

```
<table>
<div *ngFor="let table of uiFields | keyvalue">
<tr><td><label>{{table.key}}</label><label>{{table.value}}</table></td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
```

I am getting values one below the other, I want to display 3-4 pairs in one line. uiFields is my map containing different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <table>
    <tr><td *ngFor="let table of uiFields | keyvalue"><label>{{table.key}}</label><label>{{table.value}}</table></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: If I want only 4-5 items per row?

Comment: | slice:0:4  , use this pipe after keyvalue

Comment: I tried using <tr><td *ngFor="let table of uiFields | keyvalue | slice"0:4"><label>{{table.key}}</label><label>{{table.value}}</table></td> It displays random values from the map

Comment: It did work kind of using slice and adding if condition in tr tag <tr *ngIf="i==4"> and adding condition in div tag with let i==index.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an alternative method to check if this works for you

**codeSolution**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-12fmx9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

HTML

```
<table>
  <div>
    <tr *ngFor="let items of uiFields">
      <td *ngFor="let table of items">
        <label>{{ table.key }}</label>
        {{ table.value }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  uiFields = [
    [
      { key: 1, value: 'Rishab' },
      { key: 2, value: 'Ram' },
      { key: 3, value: 'Ramu' },
    ],
    [
      { key: 1, value: 'Rishab' },
      { key: 2, value: 'Ram' },
      { key: 3, value: 'Ramu' },
    ],
    [
      { key: 1, value: 'Rishab' },
      { key: 2, value: 'Ram' },
      { key: 3, value: 'Ramu' },
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: send your uiFields list

Comment: Updated my question and values here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hrqira?file=src/app/app.component.ts I want 3-4 values in a row each.

Comment: you have to use MAP?

Comment: above method which i have written

Comment: I am adding values in a loop cant break at 3rd or 4th everytime while inserting.